# How to handle timeslots when day starts in different hours?

Tags: c#, datetime, timeslots

I have an issue handling datetime periods when the day is divided in shifts that start in different hours. I'm looking to solve this in c#

Example 1:
I have an event that goes from let's say 20150901 06:00am  to 20150902 03:00am. The working shifts that I have is D (06:00 to 18:00) and N (18:00 to 06:00). I want to assign the event to the shifts datetime values.

```
START DATETIME      END DATETIME
20150901 0600       20150902 0300

SHIFT  START  END
D     0600   1800
N     1800   0600
```

The timeslots that i should get are:

```
DATE     SHIFT    STARTTIME    ENDTIME
20150901 D        0600         1800
20150901 N        1800         0300
```

Example 2:
The day is divided in four shift, but the day starts at 06:00am (01: 0600-1200, 02: 1200-1800, 03: 1800-2400, 04: 0000-0600). The event goes from 20150901 08:00am to 20150903 10:00am

```
START DATETIME      END DATETIME
20150901 0800       20150903 1000

SHIFT  START  END
01     0600   1159
02     1200   1759
03     1800   2359
04     0000   0559
```

The time slots i should get are:

```
DATE     SHIFT    STARTTIME   ENDTIME
20150901 01       0800        1200
20150901 02       1200        1800
20150901 03       1800        0000
20150901 04       0000        0600
20150902 01       0600        1200
20150902 02       1200        1800
20150902 03       1800        0000
20150902 04       0000        0600
20150903 01       0600        1000
```

Example 3:
The day is divided in four shift, but the day starts at 06:00am (01: 0600-1200, 02: 1200-1800, 03: 1800-2400, 04: 0000-0600). The event goes from 20150901 02:00am to 20150902 10:00am

```
START DATETIME      END DATETIME
20150901 0200       20150902 1000

SHIFT  START  END
01     0600   1159
02     1200   1759
03     1800   2359
04     0000   0559
```

The time slots i should get are:

```
DATE     SHIFT    STARTTIME   ENDTIME
20150831 04       0200        0600
20150901 01       0800        1200
20150901 02       1200        1800
20150901 03       1800        0000
20150901 04       0000        0600
20150902 01       0600        1000
```

Edited 1: To add the source code that I have.

Edited 2: To add the example 3 and correct some points made by Matt Johnson

The code works for some cases, but I'm still having errors when the event is somehow outside the shift frontiers (event starts before the first shift turn for example).

```
    public class slot
    {
        public DateTime date;
        public TimeSpan startHour;
        public TimeSpan endHour;
        public string shiftCode;
    }


    public List<slot> getSlots()
    {
        slot[] shifts = new slot[4];
        shifts[0] = new slot();
        shifts[0].startHour = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00);
        shifts[0].endHour = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);   
        shifts[0].shiftCode = "01";
        shifts[1] = new slot();
        shifts[1].startHour = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
        shifts[1].endHour = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
        shifts[1].shiftCode = "02";
        shifts[2] = new slot();
        shifts[2].startHour = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
        shifts[2].endHour = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
        shifts[2].shiftCode = "03";
        shifts[3] = new slot();
        shifts[3].startHour = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
        shifts[3].endHour = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00);
        shifts[3].shiftCode = "04";

        DateTime startEvent = new DateTime(2015, 09, 01, 08, 00, 00);
        DateTime endEvent = new DateTime(2015, 09, 03, 10, 00, 00);

        int i = 0;
        //To find the starting shift for the event
        while (!(
                shifts[i].startHour <= shifts[i].endHour
                    ? (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].startHour && startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].endHour)
                    : (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].startHour || startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].endHour)
                ))
            i++;

        DateTime slotStart = startEvent;
        DateTime slotEnd = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].endHour;

        List<slot> slotList = new List<slot>();

        while(endEvent >= slotEnd)
        {
            slot newSlot = new slot();
            newSlot.date = slotStart;
            newSlot.startHour = slotStart.TimeOfDay;
            newSlot.endHour = shifts[i].endHour;
            newSlot.shiftCode = shifts[i].shiftCode;
            slotList.Add(newSlot);
            i++;

            if (i >= shifts.Length)
                i = 0;

            if (shifts[i].startHour < newSlot.endHour)
                slotStart = slotStart.Date.AddDays(1);

            slotEnd = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].endHour;
            slotStart = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].startHour;
        }

        slot lastSlot = new slot();
        lastSlot.date = slotStart;
        lastSlot.startHour = slotStart.TimeOfDay;
        lastSlot.endHour = endEvent.TimeOfDay;
        lastSlot.shiftCode = shifts[i].shiftCode;
        slotList.Add(lastSlot);

        return slotList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? We can provide guidance but not complete solution.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add it. This is so far what i got. I would like to know if there's an easier/better approach that can solve the frontier issues.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. You need to separate the date-increment from the shift-reset:

   You have:

   ```
   if (i >= shifts.Length)
   {
       i = 0;
       slotStart = slotStart.AddDays(1);
   }
   ```

   Which should be replaced with:

   ```
   if (i >= shifts.Length)
   {
       i = 0;
   }

   if (shifts[i].startHour < newSlot.startHour)
   {
       slotStart = slotStart.Date.AddDays(1);
   }
   ```

   This was the main culprit.
2. In your test for the start time, the logic is just slightly off.  It should be:

   ```
   while (!(
       shifts[i].startHour <= shifts[i].endHour
           ? (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].startHour && startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].endHour)
           : (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].startHour || startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].endHour)
       ))
       i++;
   ```

   What you had written is just slightly different.  You were using `&&` to merge the first test with the true part, but that doesn't logically hold up when blended with the rest of the equation.
3. In general, you should consider adjusting your code to use half-open ranges.  Instead of a shift going from 06:00 to 17:59, it should go from 06:00 to 18:00.  You then use exclusive operators when testing the end point.  In other words `start <= testValue < end`.   This has several advantages, including making it easy to subtract to obtain duration, and preventing precision errors (since 17:59:59.999 is still in the range).  **NOTE: this point based on the original question before the edit.**.
4. You could probably save a lot of trouble by using LINQ instead of those loops.  Also, your naming conventions don't match normal C# style.
5. These types of problems tend to be easier to reason about when using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) types such as `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime`.  If later you need to consider time zones, daylight saving time, etc - you'll be in a much better position to map to `ZonedDateTime` values, calculate `Duration` values, or project to `Instant` values.
6. Have you considered what to do when you don't have the entire day covered by shifts?  You might want to calculate the missing period and show that as error output, or with an "UNASSIGNED" shift code.

Comment: Thank you. 1) It solves the timeslot divition, but still the date is a problem (see new example 3). 2 y 3) Thanks for pointing this out. 4 y 5) Never worked with this, I'll check to see how to 6) I haven't think about this, but yes, it can be an issue.

Can you point me what c# style conventions?

Comment: WRT conventions, you should use public properties, not public fields, and method, class, and property names should be `PascalCased` instead of  `camelCased`.  See more in [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).

Comment: See my edit.  Compare the `startHour` on both and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To help you along, the top loop could be something like:

```
var currentTime = startTime;
while(currentTime < endTime) {
    var shift = FindShift(currentTime);
    if (shift.EndTime > endTime) {
        shift.EndTime = endTime;
    }
    Print(shift);
    currentTime = shift.EndTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the resulting code that I'm using right now. So far, I tested it with several data and its working fine, even in the time borders.

I followed some of the directions that Matt Johnson gave me to make it work, so thank you Matt.

To have in consideration is that the shift days start in the first shift StartHour. This means that if a shift group start at 06:00am, the previous hours of the day belongs to the previous day.

Example:
The day is divided in four shift. The event goes from 20150901 02:00am to 20150902 04:00am. So even when it seems to start the 20150901 and end in 20150902 according to the shift days it will be 20150931 and 20150901

```
START DATETIME      END DATETIME
20150901 0200       20150902 0400

SHIFT  START  END
01     0600   1159
02     1200   1759
03     1800   2359
04     0000   0559
```

The time slots i should get are:

```
DATE     SHIFT    STARTTIME   ENDTIME
20150831 04       0200        0600
20150901 01       0800        1200
20150901 02       1200        1800
20150901 03       1800        0000
20150901 04       0000        0400
```

Source code:

```
    public class Slot
    {
        public DateTime Date;
        public TimeSpan StartHour;
        public TimeSpan EndHour;
        public string ShiftCode;
    }

    public List<Slot> GetSlots()
    {
        //Shifts Array
        Slot[] shifts = new Slot[4];
        shifts[0] = new Slot();
        shifts[0].StartHour = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00);
        shifts[0].EndHour = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);   
        shifts[0].ShiftCode = "01";
        shifts[1] = new Slot();
        shifts[1].StartHour = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);
        shifts[1].EndHour = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
        shifts[1].ShiftCode = "02";
        shifts[2] = new Slot();
        shifts[2].StartHour = new TimeSpan(18, 00, 00);
        shifts[2].EndHour = new TimeSpan(24, 00, 00);
        shifts[2].ShiftCode = "03";
        shifts[3] = new Slot();
        shifts[3].StartHour = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
        shifts[3].EndHour = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00);
        shifts[3].ShiftCode = "04";

        //Event TimeStamps
        DateTime startEvent = new DateTime(2015, 09, 01, 02, 00, 00);
        DateTime endEvent = new DateTime(2015, 09, 03, 08, 00, 00);

        if (endEvent < startEvent)
            return null;

        int i = 0;
        //To find the starting shift for the event
        while (!(
                shifts[i].StartHour <= shifts[i].EndHour
                    ? (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].StartHour && startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].EndHour)
                    : (startEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].StartHour || startEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].EndHour)
                ))
            i++;

        //to establish the date part of the datetime according to the starttime of the shift day
        startEvent = startEvent.AddTicks(-shifts[0].StartHour.Ticks).Date + startEvent.TimeOfDay;
        endEvent = endEvent.AddTicks(-shifts[0].StartHour.Ticks).Date + endEvent.TimeOfDay;

        DateTime slotStart = startEvent;
        DateTime slotEnd = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].EndHour;

        List<Slot> slotList = new List<Slot>();

        while (endEvent.Date > slotEnd.Date || (endEvent.Date == slotEnd.Date && !(
                shifts[i].StartHour <= shifts[i].EndHour
                    ? (endEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].StartHour && endEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].EndHour)
                    : (endEvent.TimeOfDay >= shifts[i].StartHour || endEvent.TimeOfDay < shifts[i].EndHour)
               )))
        {
            Slot newSlot = new Slot();
            newSlot.Date = slotStart.Date;
            newSlot.StartHour = slotStart.TimeOfDay;
            newSlot.EndHour = shifts[i].EndHour;
            newSlot.ShiftCode = shifts[i].ShiftCode;
            slotList.Add(newSlot);
            i++;

            if (i >= shifts.Length)
            {
                i = 0;
                slotStart = slotStart.Date.AddDays(1);
            }

            slotEnd = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].EndHour;
            slotStart = slotStart.Date + shifts[i].StartHour;
        }

        Slot lastSlot = new Slot();
        lastSlot.Date = slotStart;
        lastSlot.StartHour = slotStart.TimeOfDay;
        lastSlot.EndHour = endEvent.TimeOfDay;
        lastSlot.ShiftCode = shifts[i].ShiftCode;
        slotList.Add(lastSlot);

        return slotList;
    }
```